# Laravel email sending not working on server

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, cpanel, laravel-mail

I have a domain, and I created an email with the Cpanel on that server. Now when I try to use it, I get the following error.

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.info@myDomain.com
> :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
> Name or service not known

**.env**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.info@myDomain.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=info@myDomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD={mypassword}
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@myDomain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: Ensure you are using the smtp settings for the provider. Look at their help documentation or contact their support team.

Answer (score -1):

smtp.info@myDomain.com is not valid host.

Change MAIL_HOST to smtp.myDomain.com

Answer (score -1):

Once you try change
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls